# Saving rendered page as image

Tags: channel-entries, image, uploads

I'm trying to find a way to have EE automatically save a webpage as an image.

Basically when an single entry page is rendered I would also like EE to create an image of the finished page and attach it to the entry for access by a link or download. would be great to have domainame.com/images/made/{url_title}.jpg

thanks
mike

Answer (score 1):

You said page to *image*, but... if generating a PDF of the page would work for you then there are some add-ons that will convert ExpressionEngine pages to PDF:

- [2PDFcrowd](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/pdfcrowd)
- [Shine PDF](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/shine-pdf)
- [EEI_Tcpdf](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/tcpdf)
- [PDF Press](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/pdf-press)